# Dynamic partial based on DropdownList

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view with the following code

```
...
<div class="editor-field">              
            @Html.DropDownList("TypeSelector", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Calendar", Value = "Calendar" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Email", Value = "Email" } }, new { id = "TypeSelector" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)               
</div>
...
<div id="partialPlaceHolder" style="display:none;"> </div>
...
@section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
       <script>
               $('#TypeSelector').change(function () {

                   /* Get the selected value of dropdownlist */
                   var selectedID = $(this).val();

                   /* Request the partial view with .get request. */
                   $.get('/Step/Render/' + selectedID, function (data) {

                       /* data is the pure html returned from action method, load it to your page */
                       $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(data);
                       /* little fade in effect */
                       $('#partialPlaceHolder').fadeIn('fast');
                   });

               });
       </script>
```

and in my StepController I have an Action called "Render" which takes the ID from the dropdownlist and returns a partialview based on that ID.
If Email then returns the email template partial view and if calendar it returns the calendar template partial view.

This does not work, and for the life of me, I can't figure out why.

I'm fairly new to web development (10 years late i guess).

Edit:
The Action works if i just browse to it. -> to those of you wanting to actually see the code of the action -> I'm positive something is wrong with the ajax

Comment: Share your controller code please and both partial view.

Comment: The partial views are basically atm, empty (with a few lines of code to just see of they actually load.) so i find no need in actually posting them, as they would not help solve the problem. and at the moment the action just returns on of the partial views - to clarify that NOTHING HAPPENS. - "return Partialview("_EmailPartial")"

Comment: Why not you try complete ajax call for action render may be it solves the problem

Comment: What does "complete ajax call for action render" that mean?

Comment: You need to show your hidden div also as i updated in my answer...

Comment: Couple of troubleshooting questions. 1. Have you verified that the request is fired at all? 2. Have you debugged and made sure request reaches the action? 3. What result does the action return?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your script (replace the code inside the change function with `$('#partialPlaceHolder').html('this works').fadeIn('fast');` to test it). And what is the point of `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)`? You have not rendered a control for `model.Type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `@renderSection("scripts",...)` at the end of your main layout file? If it is at the top, you need to wrap any jQuery in DOM ready handlers (which they currently are lacking).

```
<script>
     $(function(){
           $('#TypeSelector').change(function () {

               /* Get the selected value of dropdownlist */
               var selectedID = $(this).val();

               /* Request the partial view with .get request. */
               $.get('/Step/Render/' + selectedID, function (data) {

                   /* data is the pure html returned from action method, load it to your page */
                   $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(data);
                   /* little fade in effect */
                   $('#partialPlaceHolder').fadeIn('fast');
               });

           });
       });
 </script>
```

The alternative to that is use a *delegated event handler* attached to a non-changing ancestor element (document being the default):

```
<script>
       $(document).on('change', '#TypeSelector', function () {

          /* Get the selected value of dropdownlist */
           var selectedID = $(this).val();

           /* Request the partial view with .get request. */
           $.get('/Step/Render/' + selectedID, function (data) {

               /* data is the pure html returned from action method, load it to your page */
               $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(data);
               /* little fade in effect */
               $('#partialPlaceHolder').fadeIn('fast');
           });
        });
 </script>
```

This allow bubbled events to be caught by an element that does exist already and the jQuery selector (`'#TypeSelector'`) only run at event time (not event registration time).